# Not able to bring data into a D3 choropleth map

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js

I'm having trouble incorporating John Hopkins coronavirus data into a D3 choropleth, I'm quite new so there's likely a fundamental thing that's missing. The code is largely swiped for various sources I've found on the internet but this is largely a learning project to teach myself D3 so well annotated answers would be greatly appreciated.

R code to get data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tools)

dat <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv")

states <- dat %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "US", 
         !grepl(",",Province.State),
         !grepl("Princess",Province.State),
         Province.State != "District of Columbia") %>% 
  pivot_longer(5:ncol(.), names_to = "Date", values_to = "Cases") %>% 
  mutate(Date = str_remove(Date,"X"),
         Date = as.Date(Date, "%m.%d.%y")) %>% 
  filter(Date == max(Date)) %>% 
  select(state = Province.State,
         cases = Cases)

counties <-  dat %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "US", 
         grepl(",",Province.State),
         !grepl("Princess",Province.State),
         Province.State != "Washington, D.C.") %>% 
  separate(Province.State, c("county", "state"), ", ") %>% 
  mutate(county = str_remove(county, " County")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(6:ncol(.), names_to = "Date", values_to = "Cases") %>% 
  mutate(Date = str_remove(Date,"X"),
         Date = as.Date(Date, "%m.%d.%y")) %>% 
  filter(Date == max(Date)) %>% 
  select(county = county,
         state,
         cases = Cases)

#write.csv(states, "state_cases.csv",row.names=FALSE)
#write.csv(counties, "county_cases.csv",row.names=FALSE)

#FIPS=====================================================================+++++

#county_fips <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kjhealy/fips-codes/master/state_and_county_fips_master.csv") %>% 
#  select(id = fips,
#         name,
#         state) %>% 
#  mutate(id = str_pad(as.character(id), 5, pad = "0"),
#         name = str_remove(name, " County"),
#         name = toTitleCase(tolower(as.character(name))),
#         id = case_when(grepl("000", id) ~ str_sub(id, end=-4),
#         TRUE ~ id))
#
#write.csv(county_fips, "county_fips.csv",row.names=FALSE)

county_fips <- read.csv("county_fips.csv")

cases <- county_fips %>% filter(is.na(state)) %>% 
  left_join(states, by= c("name" = "state")) %>% 
  select(-state) %>% 
  rbind(
    county_fips %>% filter(!is.na(state)) %>% 
      left_join(counties, by= c("name" = "county","state" = "state")) %>% 
      select(-state)
  )

write.csv(cases, "cases.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Coronavirus Cases</title>
    <style>
        .background {
            fill: none;
            pointer-events: all;
        }

        #states {
            fill: none;
        }

        #states .active {
            display:none;
        }

        #state-borders {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 1px;
            stroke-linejoin: round;
            stroke-linecap: round;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .county-boundary {
            fill: 'grey';
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: .5px;
        }

        .county-boundary:hover, .state:hover {
            fill: rgba(121, 121, 121, 0.2);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>

    <div class="viz"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([1, 10])
            .rangeRound([600, 860]);

        var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
            .domain(d3.range(0, 9))
            .range(d3.schemeBlues[9]);

        var margin = {
            top: 10,
            bottom: 10,
            left: 10,
            right:10
        }, width = parseInt(d3.select('.viz').style('width'))
            , width = width - margin.left - margin.right
            , mapRatio = 0.5
            , height = width * mapRatio
            , active = d3.select(null);

        var svg = d3.select('.viz').append('svg')
            .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right);

        svg.append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'background center-container')
            .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .on('click', clicked);

        var promises = [
            d3.json("us-10m.v1.json"),
            d3.csv("cases.csv", function(d) { 
                cases.set(d.id, +d.name +d.cases); 
            })
        ]

        Promise.all(promises).then(ready)

        var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
            .translate([width /2 , height / 2])
            .scale(width);

        var path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr('class', 'center-container center-items us-state')
            .attr('transform', 'translate('+margin.left+','+margin.top+')')
            .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

        function ready(us) {

            g.append("g")
                .attr("id", "counties")
                .selectAll("path")
                .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("fill", function(d) { 
                var sn = CountyNames.get(d.id)
                d.rate = cases.get(countyNames.get(d.id)) || 0
                var col =  color(d.rate); 
                if (col) {
                    return col
                } else {
                    return '#ffffff'
                }
            })
                .attr("class", "county-boundary")
                .on("click", reset);

            g.append("g")
                .attr("id", "states")
                .selectAll("path")
                .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("fill", function(d) { 
                var sn = StateNames.get(d.id)
                d.rate = cases.get(stateNames.get(d.id)) || 0
                var col =  color(d.rate); 
                if (col) {
                    return col
                } else {
                    return '#ffffff'
                }
            })
                .attr("class", "state")
                .on("click", clicked);


            g.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                .attr("id", "state-borders")
                .attr("d", path);

        }

        function clicked(d) {
            if (d3.select('.background').node() === this) return reset();

            if (active.node() === this) return reset();

            active.classed("active", false);
            active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

            var bounds = path.bounds(d),
                dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
                dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
                x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
                y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
                scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
                translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

            g.transition()
                .duration(750)
                .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scale + "px")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
        }


        function reset() {
            active.classed("active", false);
            active = d3.select(null);

            g.transition()
                .delay(100)
                .duration(750)
                .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
                .attr('transform', 'translate('+margin.left+','+margin.top+')');

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm just getting this: [image]

When I should be seeing something along these lines: http://bl.ocks.org/ElefHead/ebff082d41ef8b9658059c408096f782

Comment: What errors does your javascript console return?

Comment: I don't see any errors when I run it, it's just not passing the data into the fill attr.